# Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec() permission denied

Tags: java, bash

I need to create a private key with my Java application. I'm using the Runtime.getRuntime().exec() method to execute via bash the ssh-keygen command, but I keep getting the error message "Saving key failed: Permission denied".

I get the following logs:

```
Executing command as user = foo
Saving key "/home/foo/stir_shaken/sks/pvtk_20221014215557_ES256.pem" failed: Permission denied
```

The directory permissions:

```
[foo@bastion stir_shaken]$ pwd
/home/foo/stir_shaken
[foo@bastion stir_shaken]$ ll | grep sks
drwx------. 2 foo foo    29 Oct 14 21:37 sks
```

Here is my snippet:

```
int i;
StringBuilder inputStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder errorStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
try {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"bash", "-c", "whoami"});
    while((i=process.getInputStream().read()) != -1) {
        char value = (char) i;
        inputStringBuilder.append(value);
    }
        
    FileLogger.logNoticeMsg(className, methodName, "Executing command as user = " + inputStringBuilder.toString());
    process.waitFor();
        
    process = Runtime.getRuntime()
    .exec(new String[] {"bash", "-c", "ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -N \"\" -f /home/foo/stir_shaken/sks/pvtk_20221014215557_ES256.pem"});
    while((i=process.getErrorStream().read()) != -1) {
        char value = (char) i;
        errorStringBuilder.append(value);
    }
    
    FileLogger.logError(className, methodName, errorStringBuilder.toString());
    process.waitFor();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to execute `touch <filename from error message>` as user foo? If that doesn't work your Java code will always fail no matter what you do.

Comment: if the directory is OK, maybe there is already a (protected) file with that name there (will be after command from previous comment)

Comment: Plenty of other possible ways it could be broken depending on how the Java code is deployed -- for example, a systemd service with conservative/secure settings will see most of the filesystem as read-only _even if_ it's otherwise running as a user account with write to those directories. This is really a job for your friendly local sysadmin (or otherwise someone who understands the UNIX security model and can inspect your permissions and settings), not for Stack Overflow: it's not the code itself that's the problem.

Comment: That said, there's no good reason to use `bash` here at all. There's no reason to expect it to fix the immediate problem, but a `String[]{"ssh-keygen", "-b", "2048", "-t", "rsa", "-N", "", "-f", "/path/to/your.pem"}` array will avoid shell-specific vulnerabilities, and be a tiny bit faster to run. (For example, if you extend the code to let part of the filename be parameterized, you don't want someone inserting `$(rm -rf ~)` into it to be able to try to delete your home directory).

Comment: @Robert yes, I have successfully tried

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for your advice about not using bash, I'm now using the class KeyPairGenerator